# JSON Parse fail with special characters

Tags: javascript, json

I have created a JSON and it is showing error on value of REF ID1, Can someone helpme out...

```
{
    "stat": "OK",
    "items": [
        {
            "userid": "___",
            "usereMail": "___@needs.email.com",
            "refId1": "~!@#$%^&*()_+?": |\/;\}{\][`",
            "status":1,
            "expireon":"Never"
        }
]
}
```

Comment: You have an unescaped double quote in that value. You have to escape it.

Comment: check json code online using http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include a `"` as data in a string in a JSON text, you have to escape it with a slash, otherwise it is treated as the closing delimiter for the string.

```
?\":
```

Comment: @PrasathK — Given that he knows exactly which property is causing the property, I don't think a larger example is really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "stat": "OK",
    "items": [
        {
            "userid": "___",
            "usereMail": "___@needs.email.com",
            "refId1": "~!@#$%^&*()_+?\": |/;}{][`",
            "status":1,
            "expireon":"Never"
        }
]
}
```

remove the this character ( \ ) and try, it work for me